# PBW theorem for quantum Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, quantum-groups

Does PBW-theorem exists for quantum Lie algebras? I also appreciate your help in finding papers related to this theorem for the case of Quantum Lie algebras.

Comment: Do you mean "quantum groups" (i.e Drinfeld-Jimbo algebras) ? If yes, did you look inside Lusztig's book (I think there should be a proof but I am not sure).

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet I studied a paper from "Gustav W. Delius" as an introduction to Quantum Lie algebras. Quantum Lie algebras are generalizations of Lie algebras whose structure constants are power series in $h$.

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't know it. But PBW theorem is for the universal enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak g$. So are you sure that the universal enveloping algebra of a quantum Lie algebra isn't a quantum group (i.e $U_q$) ?
Also, maybe the paper "the diamond lemma for rings" can help, I saw people proving PBW-type theorem using this lemma.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I hope this lemma help.

Comment: Maybe this paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.563.8430&rep=rep1&type=pdf might be of some interest for your purposes.